# override create method to create records of another model

Tags: python, odoo

i need to override the create method for a model. i have two models.

1.'person_travel'

2.'person_calender'

what i am planning to do is  when i create a record for the model travel, it should automatically create the record of the model 'person_calender'.

my ultimate aim is while creating a travel record it have a date field. i need my calender view to display an event on that date.

this is my first model.

```
class Travel(models.Model):
 _name = 'person_travel'

name = fields.Char('Travel name',size=64,required=True)
package = fields.Many2one('package_travel','Package',required=True)
travel_Mode = fields.Selection((('a','Bus'), ('b','Van'), ('c','Car'), ('d','Flight'), ('e','Train'), ('f','Ship'), ('g','Motor cycle'), ('h','Other')),'Travel mode')
from_Place = fields.Char(size=64)
To_Place = fields.Char(size=64)
status = fields.Selection((('a','Pending'), ('b','Planned'), ('c','Done')),'Status')
start_date = fields.Date('Start date')
end_date = fields.Date('End date')
ticket_number = fields.Char(size=64)
seat_number = fields.Char(size=64)
description = fields.Text(size=64)
one_to_many = fields.One2many('carry_item','one_to_many')

@api.model
def create(self, values):
    print values
```

and this is my second model....

```
class Calender(models.Model):
_name = 'person_calender'

start = fields.Date('start')
# stop = fields.Datetime('stop')
state = fields.Many2one('person_manage')

subject = fields.Char(size=64)
category = fields.Selection((('a','Important'), ('b','Business'), ('c','Personel'), ('d','Business'), ('e','Travel'), ('f','Medical'), ('g','Finance'),('h','Anniversary'),('i','Birthday')),'category')
description = fields.Text(size=64)`
```

Comment: Satckoverflow is great resource to get your problem fixed. but you should  not throw sudo code and ask people to make it work based of your pseudo code.

Comment: stack over flow don't allow me to add a question without code... it tells this qn doesn't meet quality standards..that is why i put the codes here

Answer (score 6):

Their are tons of mistakes you need to fix. Naming convention are totally wrong. fields string and manyone comodel_name and so on... you need to fix.

Anyway If you see I have added code on how to create a record on create some record. that will give you idea to complete record field values.

```
class Calender(models.Model):
   _name = 'person.calender'

   start_date = fields.Date(string='Start Date')
   stop_date = fields.Datetime(string='Stop Date')
   state = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='person.manage')
   name = fields.Char(size=64, string="Subject")
   category = fields.Selection((('a','Important'), ('b','Business'), ('c','Personel'), ('d','Business'), ('e','Travel'), ('f','Medical'), ('g','Finance'),('h','Anniversary'),('i','Birthday')),'category')
   description = fields.Text(size=64)

class Travel(models.Model):
    _name = 'person.travel'

    name = fields.Char('Travel name',size=64,required=True)
    package = fields.Many2one('package_travel','Package',required=True)
    travel_Mode = fields.Selection((('a','Bus'), ('b','Van'), ('c','Car'), ('d','Flight'), ('e','Train'), ('f','Ship'), ('g','Motor cycle'), ('h','Other')),'Travel mode')
    from_Place = fields.Char(size=64)
    To_Place = fields.Char(size=64)
    status = fields.Selection((('a','Pending'), ('b','Planned'), ('c','Done')),'Status')
    start_date = fields.Date('Start date')
    end_date = fields.Date('End date')
    ticket_number = fields.Char(size=64)
    seat_number = fields.Char(size=64)
    description = fields.Text(size=64)
    one_to_many = fields.One2many('carry_item','one_to_many')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = super(Travel, self).create(vals) 
        if record.start_date  and record.end_date:
            self.env['person.calender'].create({
                'start_date': record.start_date,
                'end_date': record.end_date,
                'name': record.name,
            })
        return res_id
```

Bests